# Convert string value into html format in php

Tags: php

Any one know how to convert string value into html format in php?
For Example:

```
$string = "Hello World!!
           How are you?"
```

If I echo $string, it will display like this:

```
Hello World!!How are you?
```

Instead of:

```
Hello World!!
How are you?
```

Any way php can conver the $string into html format? If I input:

```
$string = "Hello World!!
           How are you?"
```

Php will convert it to become:

```
$string = "Hello World!!<br>How are you?"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You’re looking for the [`nl2br` function](http://docs.php.net/nl2br) that adds an HTML line break tag `<br />` to every physical line break sequence (`\n`, `\r` or `\r\n`):

```
\n    →  <br />\n
\r    →  <br />\r
\r\n  →  <br />\r\n
```

Comment: Keep in mind this will only convert the carriage returns (enter characters) into <br /> tags.

Comment: @Mladen Mihajlovic: No it doesn’t. It adds a HTML line break to every physical line break sequence: `\r\n`, `\n` and `\r` → `<br />\r\n`, `<br />\n` and `<br />\r`

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "Hello World!!
       How are you?";
echo nl2br($string);
```